# Extension field with a primitive $n$th root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it in general true that given a field $K$ and an integer $n\ge 1$, we can find an extension field $L\supseteq K$ containing a **primitive** $n$th root of unity?

Comment: Obviously, we can choose the splitting field of $X^n - 1$. But does that always contain a *primitive* $n$th root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You suggest we can consider the splitting field of $X^n - 1$: if $n \neq 0$ in $K$, then such a field has $n$ distinct $n$-th roots of unity. And since any finite group of roots of unity in a field must be cyclic....

Also, the roots of the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial are always primitive $n$-th roots of unity. (again requiring $n \neq 0$ in $K$)